# Do storage MPT branch nodes contain values?

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries

when reading through the specs of Merkle-Patricia-Trees, I was wondering if branch nodes of storage tries ever contain values?

It is my understanding, that the last array element of a branch node contains a value in case the trie was fully traversed for a given key. This occurs when we happen to have keys of different length, I guess? For the storage trie, keys are first hashed to mitigate DoS attacks building long paths, so we always have fixed length keys.

Is my assumption correct that values in the storage trie are always stored in leaf nodes, because the key is of fixed length?